# When i try to install any module with npm i get this

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /forever/forever-monitor/chokidar/fsevents: 
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14 
npm WARN embedly@0.3.2 No license field.
```

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to install `fsevent` which is native to OSX (mac). Are you sure you get that on every other modules you tried to install?

Answer (score 0):

These are just warning so not critical fatal errors but should be paid attention to in order to prevent problems in the future.

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /forever/forever-monitor/chokidar/fsevents: 
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
```

This is saying that `fsevents` has some optional dependencies that weren't installed. It's also saying that your architecture, most likely your operating system, isn't supported for this package.

```
npm WARN embedly@0.3.2 No license field.
```

The developer of this package didn't add a license field to the package.json file for the package. Not an error, not something you can fix, just something the developer of the package should add in at some point.